# Getting a UK visa at Calais

Tags: united-kingdom

My mum is a Moldovan national holding a biometric passport which allows her to travel to PARIS. I am a U.K.sitizen. I would like her to visit me at Christmas. Can she get a two weeks entry visa to the U.K. at Calais?

Comment: The question is not for Expatriates but for Travel.SE.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on Travel.SE

Comment: @JanDoggen, Ex Patriot: I agree that this question is a *better* fit for [Travel.SE], but arranging a visit by a parent with foreign nationality is a problem that is far more likely to face expatriates and naturalized citizens than the native born.

Comment: Welcome, Angela; while this may be moved to the Travel site, your mother would need a [UK Standard Visitor visa](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa) which *cannot* be obtain at the border. Have her apply immediately at the [TLScontact centre](https://uk.tlscontact.com/md/kiv/page.php?pid=center_info) and consider the priority service (for a fee) as little time remains before the holiday.

Answer (score 1):

No.  She should [apply online](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa/apply), during which she will have to book an appointment at a [visa application center](https://www.gov.uk/find-a-visa-application-centre).  There is one in Paris, and there is one in Chisinau.

Comment: Visa application center in Paris doesn't matter in this case though because it should be applied in the country of residence.

Comment: @ExPatriot the UK is less strict about that than the Schengen area.

Comment: It takes several weeks for processing the documents and one needs a postal address. I'm not sure that documents from a tourist would be accepted.

Comment: @ExPatriot Everything the parent submits will be "documents from a tourist." Perhaps you're affirming that the parent can't apply for a visa at the border, and actually mean "documents from a tourist proffered at the border to secure a visa."

Comment: @David I mean the parent would be a tourist (not a resident) in the country of appliance (in Paris).

Comment: @ExPatriot She would be a tourist indeed in France. OTOH, if the UK permits the visa application or interview to occur in a country other than that of the applicant's citizenship, as phoog suggests, then it shouldn't matter.

Comment: @David I think the very point of "I'm not sure that documents from a tourist would be accepted" is to say that I might be wrong. I frankly haven't looked into it in a few years, but what I remember is that they do accept such applications with the caveat that it may be more difficult to evaluate them compared to applications submitted in the place of residence.  I guess that this implies that borderline applications are more likely to be refused.

Comment: @phoog I just wandered around the *Apply for a UK Visa* and *Find a Visa Application Centre* pages, and found nothing that requires the applicant to use a centre in the same country of the applicant's residence or citizenship. OTOH, it makes perfect sense that documents from the applicant's home country are more likely to be familiar and understood at the centre in that same country. I wrote above "...[I]t shouldn't matter." But I agree that it might.